# Confused about word boundary

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I have been researching this a lot, but I am still not clear on it. What does *word boundary* mean? What does it do?

So, for example, could someone explain this command to me please?

```
egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b' filename.sh
```

Comment: A "word boundary" is whatever the tool used defines as such... some consider nospace/space or space/nospace a word boundary, others consider a "word" as composed of `[azA-Z0-9_]`. Check the manual for `egrep(1)`, perhaps the doumentation for the regular expressions in use.

Answer (score 12):

As described [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), for example, it matches *between* words:

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> 1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
> 2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
> 3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Here are examples of each of those cases:

1. For the string `foobar`, the first case matches

   ```
    foobar
   ^-----here
   ```
2. For the string `foobar`, the second case matches

   ```
   foobar
         ^--here
   ```
3. For the string `foo bar`, the third case will match

   ```
   foo bar
      ^--here, because space is not a word character
   ```

What qualifies as a word character depends on the specific regular expression implementation. In all cases however, letters (`[a-z]` and `[A-Z]`), numbers (`[0-9]`) and `_` are considered word characters.

---

So, the example regex you posted (`\b[A-Z]+\b`) means find the longest string that is between two word boundaries and that consists of upper case letters only. It might be easier to explain by example:

```
echo "FOOBAR" | egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b'   # Works
echo "FOO BAR" | egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b'  # Works
echo "aFOOBARb" | egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b' # Does not work, we want capitals only
echo "12345" | egrep '\b[A-Za]+\b'   # Does not work, no letters
echo "1FOOBAR2" | egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b' # Does not work, 1 and 2 are word chars
echo "_FOOBAR_" | egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b' # Does not work, _ is a word char
echo "#FOOBAR$" | egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b' # Works, # and $ are not word chars
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, just note that Solaris' `egrep` (nor `/usr/xpg4/bin/egrep`) does not treat `\b` this way. For example, `echo "FOOBAR" | egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b'` would not match.

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b' filename.sh
```

Lets break it up:

1. `[A-Z]` represents any one character in the character class 
   `[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]`.
2. `[A-Z]+` represents one or more occurrence of upper case characters.
   Example matches would be : `A`, `HELLO`, `IS`, `I`, `ELEPHANT`, etc.
3. `'\bINDIA\b'` : is exactly like a WHOLE WORD search for the word `INDIA` in upper case. It would **NOT** match `INDIANA`.
   Thus applying the same principle - `'\b[A-Z]+\b'` would look 
   for whole words having one or more letters in upper case.
4. Thus `egrep '\b[A-Z]+\b' filename.sh` would search for words having one or more letters all in upper case in the file - `filename.sh`.

`\b` - is exactly like a whole word search.